# How do I split text by "," and get rid of the "," in java?

Tags: java

I want to split and get rid of the comma's in a string like this that are entered into a textfield:

1,2,3,4,5,6

and then display them in a different textfield like this:

123456

here is what i have tried.

```
   String text = jTextField1.getText();

    String[] tokens = text.split(",");
    jTextField3.setText(tokens.toString());
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't you simply replace the `,` ?

```
text = text.replace(",", "");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're going to put it back together again, you don't need to split it at all. Just replace the commas with the empty string:

```
jTextField3.setText(text.replace(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is what you really want to do (e.g. you need to use the individual elements somewhere before concatenating them) the following snippet should work:

```
String s1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
String ss[] = s1.split(",", 0);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : ss) {
  // Use each element here...
  sb.append(s);
}
String s2 = sb.toString(); // 123456
```

Note that the [String#split(String)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method in Java has strange default behavior so using the method that takes an additional int parameter is recommended.

Comment: `s1.split(",", 0);` is not different than `s1.split(",")`. See the JavaDoc which explicit declares that it is exactly the same; also if you look at the source, `split(String)` just calls `split(String, int)` with 0 as the second parameter.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I just got into the habit of using the int parameter version because it forces me to be aware of the fact that the default split discards trailing empty strings, which caused some debugging headaches on a project.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe that call to split will get rid of the commas.  And it should leave tokens an array of just the numbers

Comment: Although a text.replace(",", ""); would work as Bozho suggested

Comment: when you do the toString() i believe it uses commas to delimit the array, hence the commas reappearing.

Comment: toString() is not defined on arrays, is it?

Comment: Well, you could loop through the elements of the array and print them then.

Comment: @Po; toString() is a method of Object and so is defined for all classes. Per the docs: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object[]%29